# compressing a tar.gz into something smaller

Tags: linux, wordpress

I backed up a wordpress install that I'm working on. It's around 65Gig. Is there a way to compress a tar.gz file to something even smaller? The reason it's so big is that it has ton of videos in the source code.

Here is the ls -lh

```
-rw-------  1 odyssey odyssey  65G Feb 29 14:00 backup-2.29.2016_12-49-50_odyssey.tar.gz
```

Comment: Provided the videos are already compressed, you won’t be able the reduce the size much more.

Comment: What sort of compression do you expect?  Simplest solution, don't backup the videos, in the same archive as the database/source

Comment: videos should be much, much  smaller, unless it is for LAN use only

Answer (score 2):

So compressing the tar.gz itself probably isn't going to be much help, since you're trying to recompress already compressed data :)

There are other tools you can use that provide better compression ratios than `gzip`, but at a cost of (sometimes ludicrously) increased compression/decompression time.

Someone over on AskUbuntu [already put together a phenomenal answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236598/best-compression-method) as to exact numbers on what the better compression methods are, but you couldn't go wrong by trying `p7zip` (available from most package managers)

Remember though that video files in most cases are *already compressed*, so the gains by using a much better algorithm probably won't be great.